# converting numpy arrays without loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D numpy array of size N that I would like to convert into a numpy array of size N*N where each element is made up of two elements from the original matrix, so that every possible combination of entries from the original array is in the final matrix
e.g.

```
the input matrix
a = [1,2,3]

the result I would like
b = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],
    [2,1],[2,2],[2,3],
    [3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
```

However the catch is I can't use any loops to do it, only inbuilts from numpy, scipy and matlpotlib
Is this possible?

Comment: `np.array(b).shape` should show (9,2).  Do you want that or (3,3,2).  In the list format that would have another layer of nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use `meshgrid` to achieve this:

```
import numpy as np
def product(*arrays):
    return np.array(np.meshgrid(*arrays)).T
```

Which will give us:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])

product(arr, arr) 
# array([[[1, 1],
#         [1, 2],
#         [1, 3]],
# 
#        [[2, 1],
#         [2, 2],
#         [2, 3]],
# 
#        [[3, 1],
#         [3, 2],
#         [3, 3]]])
```

This solution uses native `numpy` loops so we don't have to rely on `stdlib` python loops.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion spaghetti:

```py
def recursive_add_outer(array, newArr, iterator):
    if(iterator < len(array)):
        recursive_add_inner(array, newArr, iterator, 0)
        iterator += 1
        recursive_add_outer(array, newArr, iterator)
    else:
        print(newArr)
def recursive_add_inner(array, newArr, iterator, inneriterator):
    if inneriterator < len(array):
        item = []
        item.append(array[iterator])
        item.append(array[inneriterator])
        newArr.append(item)
        inneriterator += 1
        recursive_add_inner(array, newArr, iterator, inneriterator)
    else:
        return newArr
def main():
    a = [1,2,3]
    #target: b = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
    recursive_add_outer(a, [], 0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combinations for itertools and map for that by adding 3 different lists:
1) the combination of each part in a list.
2) the combinations of all items in the `a` list.
3) the combinations of all items in the reversed `a` list.

```
from itertools import combinations

b = list(map(lambda x: [x, x], a)) + list(map(lambda x: list(x), combinations(a, 2))) + list(map(lambda x: list(x), combinations(a[::-1], 2)))
print(b)
```

Output

```
[[3, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1], [3, 2], [3, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` in the following way and get the desired result:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
a = [1,2,3]
res = list(it.product(a, repeat=2))
res = np.array(res)
res = res.reshape(3, 3, 2)
print(res.shape) # (3, 3, 2)
```

`res` is for the given `a`:

```
[[[1 1]
  [1 2]
  [1 3]]

 [[2 1]
  [2 2]
  [2 3]]

 [[3 1]
  [3 2]
  [3 3]]]
```